How to prove the Maximal inequality $P(\sup_{t \ge 0} M(t)\ge \lambda) \le \frac{1}{\lambda}E(M(0))$ for nonnegative right-continuous supermartingale?
I'm confused when dealing with a problem about martingale.
Set a filtered probability space $(\Omega,{\mathcal F},\{{\mathcal F}_t\},P)$, and $M=M(t),t\geq 0$ is a right continuous nonnegative local martingale defined on it (a nonnegative local martingale must be a supermaringale). Whether the Maximal inequality
\begin{equation}
P(\sup_{t \ge 0} M(t)\ge \lambda) \le \frac{1}{\lambda}E(M(0)) \quad \lambda>0
\end{equation}
holds?
Here is my train of thought:
Define the stopping time $\tau_= \inf\{t\ge 0, M(t) \ge \lambda\}$, then from the rightcontinuous property, one has $M(\tau) \ge \lambda$. Also notice that $\{\tau <\infty\}=\{\sup_{t \ge 0} M(t)\ge \lambda\}$, hence we conclude that
\begin{equation}
\lambda P(\sup_{t \ge 0} M(t)\ge \lambda)=\lambda P(\tau<\infty)\le\int_{\{\tau<\infty\}}M(\tau)\, dP= E\left[M(\tau);\tau<\infty\right].
\end{equation}
Therefore, if $$E\left[M(\tau);\tau<\infty\right]\le E\left[M(0)\right]$$ hold for a supermartingale (or local martingale, if the property of local martingale is needed). we can get the consequence. But does such an inequality hold? Why?

In the title we are talking about supermartingales but the question implies a local-martingale, which of the two are you interested in?

@Daan Sorry, I will modify the description. In fact I'm interested in the property of supermartingale.

You could use the fact that the stopped process $M(t\wedge \tau)$ is a non-negative supermartingale.

@John Dawkins If $M$ is a martingale, then many books say that $M(t \land \tau)$ is a martingale also, but I haven't see similar conclusion for supermartingale. Can you provide a reference material?

You should probably check optional stopping theorem.

From Theorem 3.25 of Le Gall J F. Brownian motion, martingales, and stochastic calculus[M]. Springer International Publishing Switzerland, 2016.
Giving a nonnegative supermartingale and two stopping time $U,V$ with $U\le V$, we have:
$$
M(U)\ge E[M(V)|{\mathcal F}_U].
$$
Taking $U=0$, $V=\tau$, we get the consequence.

How are you defining $M(U)$ on the event ${U=\infty}$?

@ John Dawkins A nonnegative supermartingale converges a.s. as $t$ goes to infty.

True enough. So by $M(U)$ you mean $\lim_{t\to\infty}M(t\wedge U)$?

Yes， you can also this $M(U)$  as $M(U(\omega),\omega)$.
